# PHP ffmpeg output location

Tags: php, ffmpeg

My website allow users to upload video files to the server. Original file will be move to folder "Original" ffmpeg will compress the video and store the video in 480p folder. how to i setup ffmpeg so that it will store output of the compressed video file into original/480p?

Partial code of upload.php

```
$target_dir = "Original/"; //where you want to upload the files to
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newFileName = $target_dir.sha1(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'480p'.'.'.$fileType;
//$newFileName = $target_dir.sha1(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'-'.time().'.'.$fileType;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newFileName);
```

using this FFMPEG command

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i ".$newFileName." -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"480p\\{$newFileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

i get the error 
    480p\Original/ffbaf58f1231628f9ac2a583f038b51719006ec6480p.mp4: No such file or directory

i will like the output to be stored in original/480p/compressed-video-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to create a folder in your server: `original/480p`
Then change the code to:

```
$target_dir = "original/"; //where you want to upload the files to
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newFileName = $target_dir.'/480p/'.sha1(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'480p'.'.'.$fileType;
//$newFileName = $target_dir.sha1(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['file']['name']), PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'-'.time().'.'.$fileType;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $newFileName);
```

FFmpeg command:

```
shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i ".$target_file.".".$fileType." -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$newFileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");
```

Comment: fmmpeg output original/video.mp4.mp4: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you try to replace this?
`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file);`
And then:
`shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i ".$target_file." -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$newFileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");`

Comment: just notice if the user video files have spaces the video will not be compress.. any way to resolve that?

Comment: Did the script above worked?
For the file name contain space, just simple add quote in the target file name:
`shell_exec("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -i \"$target_file\" -c:v libx264 -s:v 854x480 -c:a copy \"{$newFileName}\" > logfile.txt 2>&1");`